# Share a team viewer enabled computer between multiple accounts

Tags: teamviewer

Can I share a teamviewer enabled computer between multiple accounts?

I mean I and my friend both have our common server on our personal Team Viewer panel.

Comment: Have you tried to see if it would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? You have your TV account. You add the computer login to your account. Your friend does the same.